# Lat Longs in raster brick lost when importing NetCDF file in R

Tags: r, gis, raster, netcdf

test <- brick(file.name)
My data is very large and it would be difficult to upload.

I read in a NetCDF file using this code. The NetCDF file has lat longs included i the file. I know this because I can extract them (see below). However, when I read the netCDF file in as a brick, the brick's extent does not reflect the lat long that are in the netCDF file. It simply seems to center the raster in the center of the continental US (see first plot below):

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

test <- brick(file.name)
test

class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 141, 240, 33840, 7273  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 25000, 25000  (x, y)
extent     : -3e+06, 3e+06, -1762500, 1762500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : C:/Users/anfangen/Box/Environmental-Data/Model-Pollen-Data/Raw-Data/RAGcount_1997-2016.nc 
names      : X1997.01.02.00.00.00, X1997.01.03.00.00.00, X1997.01.04.00.00.00, X1997.01.05.00.00.00, X1997.01.06.00.00.00, X1997.01.07.00.00.00, X1997.01.08.00.00.00, X1997.01.09.00.00.00, X1997.01.10.00.00.00, X1997.01.11.00.00.00, X1997.01.12.00.00.00, X1997.01.13.00.00.00, X1997.01.14.00.00.00, X1997.01.15.00.00.00, X1997.01.16.00.00.00, ... 
Date/time  : 1997-01-02 00:00:00, 2016-12-29 00:00:00 (min, max)
varname    : count
```

If I pull the lat longs out using I can see that they exist:

```
test_nc_open <- nc_open(file_name.nc')

## Get the lat longs for the ragweed file. These are in matrix form. It is as yet unclear to me why we need them in this form. 
lat <- ncvar_get(test_nc_open, varid = 'xlat')
lon <- ncvar_get(test_nc_open, varid = 'xlon')

lat

           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]    [,11]    [,12]
  [1,] 18.86005 19.05895 19.25808 19.45742 19.65697 19.85674 20.05672 20.25690 20.45730 20.65790 20.85870 21.05970
  [2,] 18.92987 19.12906 19.32847 19.52810 19.72794 19.92799 20.12826 20.32874 20.52942 20.73031 20.93141 21.13270
  [3,] 18.99921 19.19868 19.39837 19.59828 19.79841 19.99875 20.19931 20.40007 20.60105 20.80223 21.00361 21.20520
  [4,] 19.06806 19.26781 19.46778 19.66797 19.86839 20.06901 20.26985 20.47091 20.67217 20.87363 21.07531 21.27719
  [5,] 19.13641 19.33644 19.53669 19.73717 19.93786 20.13877 20.33989 20.54123 20.74278 20.94453 21.14649 21.34866
  [6,] 19.20427 19.40458 19.60511 19.80586 20.00683 20.20802 20.40943 20.61105 20.81288 21.01492 21.21716 21.41962
  [7,] 19.27163 19.47221 19.67302 19.87405 20.07530 20.27677 20.47846 20.68036 20.88247 21.08479 21.28732 21.49006
```

I tried to set the extent manually, but when I plot the result it does not match up with other spatial layers:

```
## Get state boundaries 
states <- shapefile("GIS Data/State_boundaries/cb_2018_us_state_20m.shp")

test <- brick(file.name)
[1] "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in the file!"
[1] "var (or dimvar) name: crs"
[1] "file name: file.name.nc"


test <-
  setExtent(test, c(min(apply(lon, 2, min)), 
                    max(apply(lon, 2, max)), 
                    min(apply(lat, 2, min)), 
                    max(apply(lat, 2, max)) ), keepres =
              FALSE, snap = FALSE)

crs(test) <- crs(states)

plot(test[[1]])
plot(states, add=TRUE)
```

[image: Map of states polygon layer over raster. Note that they do not match.]
I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have looked at several other similar questions and cannot get this to work using that information.

```
print(test)

     3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float xlat[jx,iy]   
            long_name: Latitude on Cross Points
            standard_name: latitude
            units: degrees_north
            grid_mapping: crs
        float xlon[jx,iy]   
            long_name: Longitude on Cross Points
            standard_name: longitude
            units: degrees_east
            grid_mapping: crs
        float count[jx,iy,time]   
            cell_methods: time: point
            grid_mapping: crs
            coordinates: xlat xlon
            units: particles m-3
            standard_name: near-surface_particle_count
            long_name: Near-surface particle count

     3 dimensions:
        time  Size:7273   *** is unlimited ***
            long_name: time
            standard_name: time
            units: hours since 1949-12-01 00:00:00 UTC
            calendar: gregorian
            bounds: time_bnds
        iy  Size:141
            long_name: y-coordinate in Cartesian system
            standard_name: projection_y_coordinate
            units: m
            axis: Y
            _CoordinateAxisType: GeoY
        jx  Size:240
            long_name: x-coordinate in Cartesian system
            standard_name: projection_x_coordinate
            units: m
            axis: X
            _CoordinateAxisType: GeoX
```

[image: Plot in response to comment below]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are doing what you are doing. In this case, the solution you are looking for depends on what your goal is.

The file has a coordinate reference system (crs) that is not lon/lat. It seems that it does not specify what it is, or, if it does, `raster` does not understand it. You can probably get the crs from whoever provided you the file. To see if there info in the file you can do `print(test)`

The file also stores the longitude and latitude of the cells. But these are not on a regular grid, so you cannot use those. If you really need the raster data to be in lon/lat you can use something like

```
x <- projectRaster(test, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

But that leads to loss of precision, so it is best avoided. To extract values by point or polygon from the raster data, you should first transform those to the crs of the raster data. You can use `sp::spTransform` for that. After that, you can use `raster::extract`

So with SpatialPoints `p`, you can do something like this (but with the correct crs, utm 43 is certainly wrong on this case)

```
 putm <- spTransform(p, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84")) 
 e <- extract(test, putm)
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for responding. 

I have updated the post to include the results of print(test). It says "crs" but I am not sure what this means. 

I tried to change the projection as you said, but I got the following error

```
 x <- projectRaster(test, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
Error in projectRaster(test, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") : 
  input projection is NA
```

Comment: I tried setting the crs

    crs(test) <-
      "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84"

but nothing changes. 

As for why I am doing what I am doing, I have a netCDF file of predicted pollen count rastersd by day. 

I need to extract raster values to to point or polygons. Since I cannot overlay any points or polygons and have them match the raster layers, I cannot extract the values properly. 

Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: That should not change anything, as it only adds a description. But see my expanded answer.

Comment: thank you for your response. 

I fear that I am not being clear. This is still not working for me.

I used this code

test <- brick(file.name)
crs(test) <-
  "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS844"
states_utm <- spTransform(states, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84")) 

plot(test[[1]])
plot(states_utm, add=TRUE)

I placed the plot in the original post, you can see that the states do not even appear. 

How can I get the raster brick to be in the same coordinate system as the polygon file? It would seem easy since lat long are included in the netCDF file.

Comment: I have updated the original post to attempt to make my problem a bit more clear. 

I have been struggling with this for months and can't make any progress on it.

Comment: You really need to know the crs of the raster data. It certainly is not utm 43 as that does not cover the USA. Do you have any idea about what it might be? What is the data source? It is possible to use the lon/lat values, but it would be clumsy.  But, if you are desperate, you can read the ncdf file the "standard" way, with ncdf package functions, and then relating lon/lat values to the variable of interest, and represent these as points. You could then intersect these points with polygons.

Comment: OK, that's helpful to know. I will see if I can find out what the CRS is. In the mean time, I will take your latter advice, that might get me out of the pinch I am in right now.